# Paypal displaying 400 error when copoun is applied

Tags: laravel, paypal, cart

I am using paypal integration in my web application everything is working fine . Checkout is working properly but when i apply the coupon then the paypal throws the exception of 400 error. Below is my code 
I am using the daryldecode/cart for the checkout. The only problem is when I apply the coupon and move forward towards the paypal

```
public function paywithPaypal(Request $request)
{

 // dd($request->all());    

    if(Auth::guest()){
        if(Session::has('user_id')){
            $sessionUserId = Session::get('user_id');
            echo $sessionUserId;
        }
        $checkEmail= User::where('email',$request->billing_email )->first();
        if(empty($checkEmail)) {
            $user   = User::create( [
                'first_name' => $request->billing_first_name,
                'last_name'  => $request->billing_last_name,
                'email'      => $request->billing_email,
                'username'   => $request->billing_first_name,
                'password'   => bcrypt( 123456 ),
                'province'   => $request->billing_state,
                'city'       => $request->billing_town,
                'address'    => $request->billing_address_1,
                'role'       => 'Member',
            ] );
            $userId = $user->id;
        }else{
            $userId = $checkEmail->id;
        }
    }else{

        //user login
        $sessionUserId = $userId = Auth::user()->id; 
    }

        $items = [];

        \Cart::session($sessionUserId)->getContent()->each(function($item) use (&$items)
        {
            $items[] = $item;
        });
        $subtotal = \Cart::session($sessionUserId)->getSubTotal();

   // dd($subtotal);

    $line1 = $request->billing_address_1;
    $line2 = $request->billing_address_2;
    $fullname = $request->billing_first_name ." ". $request->billing_last_name;
    $state = $request->billing_state;
    $zip = $request->billing_zip;
    $phone = $request->billing_phone;
    $email = $request->billing_email;
    $city = $request->billing_town;

    //invoke new order

    $order = new Orders ;
    $order->id = $order->generateID('INV');
    $saved_order_id = $order->id;
    $shippingAddress= Paypalpayment::shippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setLine1($line1)
        ->setLine2($line2)
        ->setCity($city)
        ->setState($state)
        ->setPostalCode($zip)
        ->setCountryCode("US")
        ->setPhone($phone)
        ->setRecipientName($fullname);

    // ### Payer
    // A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
    // Use the List of `FundingInstrument` and the Payment Method
    // as 'credit_card'


    $payer = Paypalpayment::payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

    $listitem = array();
    $fees=HandlingFee::find(1);
    $fee = $fees->fee;
    $shipping = $request->shipping_fee;
    foreach($items as $key=>$item){
       $listitem[$key] = Paypalpayment::item();
       $listitem[$key]->setName($item->name)
                     ->setCurrency('USD')
                     ->setQuantity($item->quantity)
                     ->setPrice($item->price);
        $item_detail = new Order_Item_Details;
        $item_detail->order_id = $saved_order_id;
        $item_detail->item_id = $item->id;
        $item_detail->qty = $item->quantity;
        $item_detail->save();
    }

    $itemList = Paypalpayment::itemList();
    $itemList->setItems($listitem)
        ->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);

    $details = Paypalpayment::details();
    $details->setShipping($shipping)
            ->setHandlingFee($fee)
            //total of items prices
            ->setSubtotal($subtotal);
    $grandTotal = $subtotal + $fee + $shipping;

    //dd($grandTotal);

    //Payment Amount
    $amount = Paypalpayment::amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD")
            // the total is $17.8 = (16 + 0.6) * 1 ( of quantity) + 1.2 ( of Shipping).
            ->setTotal($grandTotal)
            ->setDetails($details);
    //dd($amount);
    // ### Transaction
    // A transaction defines the contract of a
    // payment - what is the payment for and who
    // is fulfilling it. Transaction is created with
    // a `Payee` and `Amount` types

    $transaction = Paypalpayment::transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription("Payment description")
        ->setInvoiceNumber($saved_order_id)
        ->setCustom($request->shipping_service);



  //   dd($transaction);

    // ### Payment
    // A Payment Resource; create one using
    // the above types and intent as 'sale'

    $redirectUrls = Paypalpayment::redirectUrls();

    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(url("/payments/success"))
        ->setCancelUrl(url("/payments/fails"));

    $payment = Paypalpayment::payment();

    $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

    $order->status = 1;
    $order->user_id = $userId;
    $order->total = $grandTotal;
    $order->subtotal = $subtotal;
    $order->shipping = $shipping;
    if($request->coupon_code == ""){
    $order->isCoupon = 0;            
    }
    else{
    $order->isCoupon = 1;
    }
    $order->isBillingDetail = 1;
    if($request->shipping_first_name <> ""){
    $order->isShippingDetail = 1;
    }
    if($request->has('order_notes')){
        $order->notes = $request->order_notes;
    }
    $order->save();

    $order_billing = new Order_Billing_Details;
    $order_billing->order_id = $order->id;
    $order_billing->first_name =  $request->billing_first_name ;
    $order_billing->last_name =  $request->billing_last_name ;
    $order_billing->company = $request->billing_company_name ;
    $order_billing->address_line_1 = $line1;
    $order_billing->address_line_2 = $line2;
    $order_billing->state = $state;
    $order_billing->city = $city;
    $order_billing->postal_code = $zip;
    $order_billing->email = $email;
    $order_billing->phone = $phone;
    $order_billing->save();

    if($request->shipping_first_name <> ""){
    $order_shipping = new Order_Shipping_Details;
    $order_shipping->order_id = $order->id;
    $order_shipping->first_name =  $request->shipping_first_name ;
    $order_shipping->last_name =  $request->shipping_last_name ;
    $order_shipping->company = $request->shipping_company_name ;
    $order_shipping->address_line_1 = $request->shipping_address_1 ;
    $order_shipping->address_line_2 = $request->shipping_address_2 ;
    $order_shipping->state = $request->shipping_state ;
    $order_shipping->city = $request->shipping_town ;
    $order_shipping->postal_code = $request->shipping_zip ;
    $order_shipping->email = $email ;
    $order_shipping->phone = $request->shipping_phone ;
    $order_shipping->save();
    }
    else{
    $order_shipping = new Order_Shipping_Details;
    $order_shipping->order_id = $order->id;
    $order_shipping->first_name =  $request->billing_first_name ;
    $order_shipping->last_name =  $request->billing_last_name ;
    $order_shipping->company = $request->billing_company_name ;
    $order_shipping->address_line_1 = $line1;
    $order_shipping->address_line_2 = $line2;
    $order_shipping->state = $state;
    $order_shipping->city = $city;
    $order_shipping->postal_code = $zip;
    $order_shipping->email = $email;
    $order_shipping->phone = $phone;
    $order_shipping->save();
    }

    try {


        // ### Create Payment
        // Create a payment by posting to the APIService
        // using a valid ApiContext
        // The return object contains the status;

        //dd(Paypalpayment::apiContext());

        $payment->create(Paypalpayment::apiContext());
        // dd($payment);
        $arrpayment = $payment->toArray();
        $order = Orders::find($saved_order_id);
        $order->paypal_invoice = $arrpayment['id'];
        $order->save();
    } catch (\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
        echo $ex->getData();
        dd($ex);
        return response()->json(["error" => $ex->getMessage()], 400);
    }
    catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
        echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message 
        } 



    $email=$request->billing_email;
     $fees=HandlingFee::find(1);
      $fee = $fees->fee;
    $data=array(
        'order' => $order,
        'name' => $request->billing_first_name.' '.$request->billing_last_name,
        'email'=>$email,
        'fee'=>$fee,
        'payPalLink' => $payment->getApprovalLink(),
    );
   Mail::send('email.placed', $data, function($message) use ($email) {
        $message->subject('New Order Received');
        $message->from('no-reply@blurack.com', 'BluRack');
        $message->to($email);
    });

    $admins=DB::table('users')
        ->select('updates_email')
        ->where('receiving_updates',1)
          ->where(function($q) {
             $q->where('role','Administrator')
                ->orWhere('role','Retailer'); 
          })->get()->toArray();
 //      ->where('role','Administrator')
    //   ->orWhere('role','Retailer')
     //  dd($admins);
    foreach($admins as $admin){
       $admin_mail=$admin->updates_email;
        //dd($admin_mail);
    Mail::send('email.orderplaced',$data, function($message) use ($admin_mail) {
        $message->subject('New Order Received');
        $message->from('no-reply@blurack.com', 'BluRack');
        $message->to($admin_mail);
   });

    }

    return redirect($payment->getApprovalLink());
    // return response()->json([$payment->toArray(), 'approval_url' => $payment->getApprovalLink()], 
   200);

}
```

I think the issue is with try catch problem?

Comment: Instead of `echo $ex-> ...`, try `\Log::error($ex->getMessage());`; that will log the error to your logs if/when it happens. You shouldn't use `echo` in a Controller, and `dd()` will stop execution if not commented out, so only use that for debugging.

Comment: This is what exactly i am doing from couple of hours but didnt get any actual response error that why the error is occuring.\Log::error($ex->getMessage()); I have tried this earlier

Comment: Hmm, the only issue here is there's a lot of code in your question, and I'm not sure what specifically would cause that error. It's a "Bad Request" error, but I'm not familiar enough with PayPal logic to know where that's occurring. Have you checked your `storage/logs/laravel.log` for errors?

Comment: Yes I checked the logs file but the exception is same .

Comment: Well, your logs should also tell you what line the error occurred on, so try to find that and specify what line in the code above is specifically causing that issue.